# Is there a countable reduced $p$-group such that the corresponding Ulm-Kaplansky invariants are infinite or zero?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

We know that countable Abelian groups are classified up to isomorphism by their Ulm-invariants.

In the course of research, the following questions have been raised for me. If anyone has an answer in this regard, I would be grateful if they could provide it to me.

Is there a countable reduced $p$-group such that the corresponding Ulm-Kaplansky invariants are infinite or zero?

In general, what sequences of ordinals can be Ulm-Kaplansky invariants of a countable reduced $p$-group?

Comment: Are you referring to abelian groups in your question as well?

Answer (score 2):

These invariants are additive with respect to arbitrary direct sums. Hence, for any countable reduced abelian $p$-group $A$, the direct sum $A^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ is still countable and reduced with invariants all either $0$ or $\aleph_0$.

The more general question is the content of exercise 42 in Kaplansky's *Infinite Abelian Groups* (as well as several exercises building up to it). Let $\lambda$ be any countable ordinal and $f$ be any function from $\lambda$ to the cardinals up to $\aleph_0$. Then $f$ is the sequence of invariants for such a group of length $\lambda$ if and only if $f$ takes on infinitely many nonzero values between any two limit ordinals $\alpha<\beta\leq \lambda$.

Comment: I did not find a reference for the following statement.   Ulm invariants are additive with respect to arbitrary direct sums.

Comment: Also, using the above result from Kaplansky, then there must exist a countable   reduced p-group such that whose Ulm invariants are the following:                                                                                                                                           f(n)=0 for all n=0, 1,2,.... and $f(\omega)=1$.

Comment: But the existence of such a group creates a contradiction. Because if $G=H\oplus K$, then all Ulm invariants of  $H$ or $K$ must be zero, and hence, $H=0$ or $K=0$, i.e., $G$ is indecomposable, a contradiction.

Comment: The additivity follows immediately from the definition, since the dimension of vector spaces is additive wrt sums. For the other question, you are quite correct, such a group cannot exist. The statement would be correct if we regard zero as a limit ordinal. Said alternatively, maybe more clearly, a function $f$ gives admissible invariants if and only if its support is unbounded below any limit ordinal in its domain. This agrees with the stated characterization for all limits larger than $\omega$ of course, but also catches your example.

Comment: If Ulm invariants are additive with respect to arbitrary direct sums, why is there an exercise (given below on page 157 of Fuchs's Infinite Abelian Groups (1370 Vol 1)?                                                                                                                                                 Exercise 8. If $A=\bigoplus_{i\in I}{A _i}$, then for the Ulm-Kaplansky invariants one has  $f_{\sigma}(A)=\sum_{i\in I} f_{\sigma}(A_i)$.

Comment: Your claim is true when we have the following:$$\frac{p^n(\oplus_{i\in I}A_i)[p]}{p^{n+1}(\oplus_{i\in I}A_i)[p]}\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I}\frac{p^nA_i[p]}{p^{n+1}A_i[p]}$$ for each $n$ and also for each ordinal $\alpha$.

Comment: Is the above relationship correct?